# Expand selection from cursor to search term in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text

I use Sublime Text often for non-coding writing, where the ability to select/highlight text from a cursor position to a search term can be handy. Is this possible with the built-in shortcuts?

To give an example, let's say I have the following text:

> Be patient till the last.
>   Romans, countrymen, and lovers! hear me for my
>   cause, and be silent, that you may hear: believe me
>   for mine honour, and have respect to mine honour, that
>   you may believe: censure me in your wisdom, and
>   awake your senses, that you may the better judge.

My cursor is under the 'p' of 'patient', and I want to select text from there to 'lovers!' In Vim, I could do `v/lovers!`, and it would expand selection from 'patient' to 'lovers'. Vi-mode in Sublime Text can't do that (and I wouldn't expect it to) ... but can Sublime Text do something like this natively?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what the norms are for answering one’s own question here, but since I got the dreaded Tumbleweed badge for this one, I figured I’d try to do it myself.

Here’s a (very inelegant) approach I came up with; only works in ST3. The basic idea is that you initiate an incremental search (or regular Find, and exit the search field with ESC), set a mark, rewind to the prior cursor position, extend selection to mark, then clear the mark. This can all be encapsulated in the following macro , then assigned to a shortcut key:

```
[
{
"args": null,
"command": "set_mark"
},
{
"args": null,
"command": "jump_back"
},
{
"args": null,
"command": "select_to_mark"
},
{   "args":
    {
        "name": "mark"
    },
"command": "clear_bookmarks"
}
]
```

It boils down to: 1) run incremental search (command-I in OS X, exits search field on enter), 2) hit shortcut key.

Two big caveats. 1) This only works in ST3, because ST2 doesn’t have a built-in function for returning to previous cursor position. 2) It will delete *all* the marks, so if you regularly use marks, you won't like this macro (though I’m sure it can be adjusted to just delete the last mark).

It's no `v/<search term>`. It’s an ugly workaround. But it works, at least for ST3. If anyone knows a more elegant way of doing this, or how to do it in ST2, please share.

Comment: Although it's nine years later, and I'm looking for a solution for NotePad++ (which does *not* support "find and extended selection"), I gave you a +1 for taking the time to pose the question and answer it with the best solution you could think of.